# How to find combination difference of a dataframe in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

for example :

```
+------+
|items |
+------+
|     1|
|    14|
|    11|
|     3|
|     0|
|  0,13|
|     8|
|     7|
|  7,11|
|    13|
+------+
```

I want to subtract each column value with other values of same column . for example subtract 1 with all other values then 14 with all other values like wise up to 13 . How is it possible ?

I tried it with a udf function but its not working .

```
 df.rdd.foreach(x => {
  val firstPoint= x.toSeq.toArray.map({
    case s: String => s.toInt
    case l: Long => l.toInt
    case d :Double => d.toInt
    case i : Int => i.toInt
    case f : Float => f.toInt
     })
     println(firstPoint.deep)
    items =  items.withColumn("col" + i, freq(firstPoint)(df.col("items")))
     i = i + 1
   })
```

It shows null pointer error .

Comment: can you give expected output dataframe?

Comment: @AkhilaV  looks like  `each column value with other values of same column` = 14 times write all column values in different order. All your results will be identical. Or I misunderstood the question...

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if people think of the use case before using Spark. It's a distributed processing engine, your dataset could be splitted on hundreds of nodes at once and if you do procedural operations like this you would generate crazy shuffle. You can't even make sure of the rows order without coalescing your dataset, which would ruin all Spark advantages. Just don't, use plain python or panda or anything else.